# How can I draw a banner or other adornment over an image using XAML in a Windows Store app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Here's basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: images with banners]

I can get the image drawn and placed appropriately, but I'm at a loss for how to draw the banners.  It's easy enough to put both elements in a Grid, but I can't figure out how to get the banner positioned/sized based on the aspect ration of the image that gets loaded.

If this was WPF I'm pretty sure I could just use an Adorner, but in WinRT I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing kuje the Adorner in WinRT. Place the image and the banner into a grid, set the banner's vertipcal alignment to top, horizontal alignment to right.

If you want the banner to always be the same size, set Stretch to None. Otherwise hook into the Loaded event of the image where you can get the image dimensions and set the banner dimensions accordingly.

Comment: I was looking for some way to do it entirely in XAML.  It's actually part of a DataTemplate and which banner (if any) to display is configured via a binding.  I need the size of the image to scale things appropriately, so I guess I have to handle the loaded event.  I ended up packaging it all up in a UserControl so I can revisit it in the future.  Thanks.